# Domain redirect

Tags: redhat, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a rewrite rule for an old domain `test.fr`.

I have placed my rule in our virtualhost in the `httpd.conf` file with rewrite engine on, I'm not sure why `.htaccess` wasn't used.

## rewrite rules for test.fr

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^test.fr [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.test.fr [NC]
RewriteRule $ http://www.test.com/france$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The issue I'm having is subsites of the domain are not transferred with the rewrite.

For example: If I go to `http://www.test.fr/abc/123` it will rewrite to `http://www.test.com/france/` but `/abc/123` after `france` is left off.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where exactly have you placed these directives? Do you have other directives? (Do you have any `.htaccess` files that might _conflict_?) Ideally, you wouldn't use mod_rewrite for this anyway. Instead you would have multiple VirtualHost containers and use the `Redirect` directive instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.test.com/france/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

If it isn't self-explanatory, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thank you for this, I have tried the above and am running into the same issue. Can you explain what's going on? It might help me trouble shoot. I'm not sure if it could be a caching issue on the server.

Comment: @AndreasRogge You need to remove the `OR` flag on the _single_ `RewriteCond` directive, otherwise the `RewriteRule` will execute _unconditionally_.

Comment: @POPEYE1716 If you are getting the "same issue" then you are likely seeing a cached response. Or you have not restarted Apache. Clear your browser cache / restart Apache and try again (but remove that `OR` flag first).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've made the changes suggested above and have restarted the App server for my redirect. Still resolving to the same where the sub-directories are left off. I'll keep researching